# Getting error XPST0017 when importing XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I can successfully run an XSLT transformation with stylesheet A. When I import stylesheet A into stylesheet B, I get the following error:

```
[2022-07-30 19:54:59]
C:\Users\dschiavon\Downloads\Customers\Customer\2007\saxon.log
Transformation filename:
web-extend.xslt
Input path:
C:\Users\dschiavon\Downloads\Customers\Customer\2007\information security policy.xml
Output path:
C:\Users\dschiavon\Downloads\Customers\Customer\2007\information security policy.xml
Transform.exe : Saxon-HE 9.7.0.7N from Saxonica
At C:\Users\dschiavon\Downloads\saxon_transform\saxon_transform.ps1:45 char:1
+ & $saxon -s:"$inputPath" -xsl:"$publish_folder\$transformation_filena ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Saxon-HE 9.7.0.7N from Saxonica:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
.NET 4.0.30319.42000 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
URIResolver.resolve href="file:/C:/Users/dschiavon/Downloads/Customers/Customer/2007/web-extend.xslt" base="null"
Using parser org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
URIResolver.resolve href="file:/C:/Users/dschiavon/Downloads/Customers/Customer/XSLT/Web.xslt" 
base="file:/C:/Users/dschiavon/Downloads/Customers/Customer/2007/web-extend.xslt"
Using parser org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
URIResolver.resolve href="file:/C:/Users/dschiavon/Downloads/Customers/Customer/XSLT/Web.xslt" 
base="file:/C:/Users/dschiavon/Downloads/Customers/Customer/2007/web-extend.xslt"
Static error in {fn:serialize($topicContent)} in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 4553 column 98 of Web.xslt:
  XPST0017: System function serialize#1 is not available with this host-language/version/license
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
Transformation finished, end of script.
```

Stylesheet B does nothing except importing stylesheet A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:ait="http://www.authorit.com/xml/authorit" 
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs ait saxon xd" extension-element-prefixes="ait saxon"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:import href="file:/C:/Users/dschiavon/Downloads/Customers/Customer/XSLT/Web.xslt" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Stylesheet A is very long (6500 lines), but the line causing the problem is this one:

```
<xsl:attribute name="data-content"><xsl:value-of select="serialize($topicContent)"/></xsl:attribute>
```

Saxon documentation does say that serialize() is obsolescent, so I tried with fn:serialize(), but got the same error.

How do I get the transformation to complete without errors? I am running Saxon-HE 9.7.0.7N on Windows.

**NOTE: I tried with Saxon-HE 10.5J and the transformation completes correctly, so the problem is only in the .NET version.**

Possibly related to [Saxon 9 HE, Java - Static errors, XTSE0210, XTSE0165, XPST0017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670920/saxon-9-he-java-static-errors-xtse0210-xtse0165-xpst0017).

Comment: The latest release of Saxon.NET HE is Saxon 10.8 HE, can't you switch to that? At least use 9.8 or later if you want to use `(fn:)serialize`, it is an XPath 3.1 function so you need a version released after the finalization of XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 and 9.8 was the first to do that. With 9.7 it might suffice to use `version="3.0"` in the XSLT but I don't remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

`fn:serialize()` was a new function introduced in XSLT 3.0, whch was finalised in 2017.

Saxon 9.7 was released in November 2015, and included partial implementation of the draft XSLT 3.0 specification. The documentation for that release clearly states:

*All XSLT 3.0 features require at least Saxon-PE. Schema-awareness, streaming, and packages require Saxon-EE.*

*XSLT 3.0 support must be explicitly enabled, for example by specifying version="3.0" in the stylesheet or by using the option -xsltversion:3.0 on the command line.*

See https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.7/index.html#!using-xsl/xslt30

If you want to use newer features of the language, you need to keep up to date with software releases. The current release is 11.4.

The function that's obsolescent is not `fn:serialize()`, but the earlier Saxon extension function `saxon:serialize()`.

Comment: Michael, thank you for the reply, but I probably did not explain the problem correctly. The function that is causing the error is not fn:serialize(), but saxon:serialize().
The problem only happens when I import my stylesheet. If I apply the stylesheet directly, no error is generated and the transformation succeeds. I want to be able to import the stylesheet and override some templates.

Comment: Saxon extension functions have generally not been supported in Saxon-HE, but Saxon 9.7 is a long time ago and I don't know offhand what the rules were then. Please upgrade to a supported release. If you can reproduce the problem in a supported release, you're welcome to raise it with Saxonica.

Comment: I tried to run the transformation with Saxon-HE 10.5J and it completes correctly. With the Java version, I manage to import my first stylesheet. The error about saxon:serialize() does not appear anymore. So I assume that it is a .Net only problem.

Comment: One final comment: Saxon 10.5N & 10.8N return error: Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'net.sf.saxon.expr.number.NumberFormatter' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type 
initializer for 'net.sf.saxon.regex.charclass.Categories' threw an exception. ---> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable 
to read categories.xml file

Which is the reason I was using 9.7 in the first place (Martin Honnen opened a ticket with Saxonica https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4983).

Comment: @DiegoSchiavon, in Saxon .NET HE 10.8? Any, at which point does `serialize($topicContent)` try to use/call a Saxon extension function? You are calling an XSLT or XPath function of that name if it is in no namespace. And the problem is, based on the error, not .NET vs Java, but simply that the old 9.7, with `version="2.0"` runs as an XSLT 2.0 processor supporting XPath 2.0 (where there is no `serialize` function).

Comment: @DiegoSchiavon, as for the .NET categories.xml problem, https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4983 suggests there is 10.5.1 .NET release that fixes it. Of course that build fix should hopefully be also in 10.8 .NET.

Comment: This is now getting messy, perhaps raise separate issues with all details on the Saxonica site if you really have that exception with Saxon .NET 10.8. The test case I have in the bug issue runs fine for me with Saxon .NET 10.8 from the command line.

Comment: Hi Martin Honnen, I tried .NET HE 10.5 (not 10.5.1, admittedly) and 10.8, but I get the categories.xml problem with both. 9.7 does not give the error, so I went with it. The original transformation runs fine in 9.7, the problem only appears when I import it into another stylesheet. I agree this is getting messy now, I will pursue this further with Saxonica.

Comment: 9.7 is not an XSLT 3.0 processor, you haven't provided any details of the first issue with .NET and I don't see, if you say you knew the bug issue with a fix release 10.5.1, you jump from an XSLT 3 processor to an XSLT 2 one. Anyway, is the original code not being imported using `version="3.0"` or `version="2.0"`?